# "git push -u origin --all" fails only from AWS virtual Linux instance - possibly ssh related

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, github, ssh

Pardon my ignorance here.

I have a local Windows machine using which if I run the following commands on a Windows cmd prompt, they all work:

- git config --global user.email "myuser@abc.com"
- git config --global user.name "myuser"
- cd Try (some dir holding a single readme file)
- git init
- git add .
- git commit -am "initial"
- git remote add origin git@mygiturl.git (URL where I want to check into)
- git remote -v
- git push -u origin --all

However, if I try running the exact same set of commands from a Linux server (EC2 instance spawned in AWS), it throws:
ubuntu@ip:~/try$ git push -u origin --all

> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I'm guessing it's possible got to do with ssh and/or authentication, but it doesn't error out with "permission denied".

If I run these same from Ubuntu Linux subsystem on Windows, the "git push -u origin --all" fails with permission denied instead.

> git@gitlab....: Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found. fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the
>   correct access rights and the repository exists.

Most likely cause to this is that your Amazon EC2 instance does not have any connectivity to the internet. This maybe be because it is in the private subnet or you have some security group rules to block the outgoing connection. If your instance is in private subnet then you may need to associate a NAT gateway and add a route table entry to allow the ec2 instance reach to the internet.

Comment: Thanks Juned. I fear that might not be the case. The application/ program that is running all these git commands is also sending out other Rest-API requests that are getting fulfilled (indicating internet connectivity). Also, all the git commands listed above all the way untiI " git remote -v" work. It's only the last git push -u that is failing.